Used to and would and time expressions

When I was a kid I would run a lot

When I was there I would study a lot

When I travelled I used to sleep a lot

For 10 years, I would/might/could do it

I used to/might/could play tennis for 15 years


My teacher told me that 1,2 and 3 are correct and 4 and 5 are wrong. She said that we don't use "would or used to" with the exact time frame but with something more vague. Do you agree with her and why is that? I'd like to ask what if I put "might and could" instead of "used to". Does it change something or even with them sentences 4 and 5 would be unidiomatic?

I would call (4) and (5) unidiomatic. It's correct that we don't normally use expressions like used to with a definite time frame. However, you might say "During the seven years that I was frequently travelling, I used to sleep a lot."(The time frame refers to the travelling, not the sleeping.)

@KateBunting  can you say something more? Why do you feel that 4 and 5 are  wrong? How do you interpret 4 and 5 in comparison to 1, 2 and 3?

I thought I had made that clear; it's unidiomatic (not grammatically wrong) to say used to when we speak of something we did for a specific length of time, as your teacher told you.

@KateBunting I think the same applies to "might" but "could" which also expresses ability would be fine with exact time frames "I could do that for 20 years" meaning was able to. Correct?

No, you can't draw any conclusions about using might or could from what Kate says about idiomatic (and syntactically valid) constructions involving used to. But there's little to be learned by randomly juggling words around like this. If you want to convey some specific meaning, describe that meaning fully using as many words as necessary, then tell us what you think might be the best way to express it succinctly. Then we can check what you come up with, because we know what you want it to mean.

So. "I might sleep a lot for 7 years vs I might sleep  a lot when I travelled" which one is good? Does it work the same way as "used to"

@FumbleFingers  I changed my question. Can you answer now?

@KateBunting same question to you if you don't mind

You haven't changed (4) and (5), so my comment still stands.

@KateBunting check now please

Your amended versions don't make sense. (Did you have the ability to play tennis for 15 years and then suddenly find you couldn't?)

@KateBunting  what about "might" does it go well  with the exact time frame or it is like "used to" and we need something more vague?

What do you want such a sentence to mean?

That sometimes I did it. That's it. Why don't you just answer my question? You said that "used to" should be used with vague time frames. Does the same apply to" might". Please, tell me yes or not and that's it

No, I can't / won't "answer" the changed question. Explain in as many words as necessary exactly what meaning you want to convey, and if appropriate, what English text you think might correctly convey that meaning. Then we can tell you if you've got it right or not. But just shuffling words around and asking whether the permutations are valid (and if so, what do they mean?) isn't a sensible way to learn a foreign language.

@FumbleFingers Is my English really that broken that you don't understand my very simple question. I asked about "used to" and you explained that it is not idomatic to use it with exact time frames like "for 5 years". It is better to use something more vague like "when I was little". Now, my question is exactly THE SAME but this time I'm asking about "might". "I might do it for 10 years, in the past". Does it sound unidiomatic too like " used to" and it's better to change "10 years" into for instance "when I was travelling". My question is that simple. Just please answer.

I have no intended meaning I just want to know the general rule

Plus thank you for your previous answers

@KateBunting please answer once you have free time

I would answer in the same way as FumbleFingers. No, "I might play tennis for 15 years" does not mean "During a certain 15-year period I sometimes played tennis".  I think you can take it as a 'rule' that you can't use any of these expressions with a definite time-frame.
